# ValueError: could not convert string to float - in google colab

Tags: python

Getting the error as shown below. 
"ValueError: could not convert string to float: "

The file has numbers

```
0.57273,0.677385,1.87446,2.06253,3.33843,5.47434,7.88282,3.52778,9.77052,9.16828



def read_anchors(anchors_path):
    with open(anchors_path) as f:
        anchors = f.readline()
        anchors = [float(x) for x in anchors.split(',')]
        anchors = np.array(anchors).reshape(-1, 2)
    return anchors



!wget  http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/data/deeplearning4/images/yolo_anchors.txt  -P drive/app
anchors = read_anchors("drive/app/yolo_anchors.txt")
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Works fine on 3.6.

Comment: i am using google colab - python 3. but version not known

Comment: Are you sure you do not have non numerical characters? Also, why don't you read it with `numpy.loadtxt`

Comment: how? anchors = np.loadtxt(anchors_path, delimiter=',')?

Comment: You almost certainly have a blank line at the end of your file. Then `anchors.split()` returns `['']` and `float()` complains about an empty string, as your reported error message shows. Add the test `if anchors:` so that your code doesn't assume there is data in the string.